# How to update Realtime Database from Cloud Function using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am creating a cloud function for my iOS app - I want it to create a Stripe customer when a user signs up (this works properly), but I can't set any data to my realtime database within the function.

Here is my latest attempt

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey)



//when user is created: 
//1.create user with Stripe
//2.update users/user.uid/registeredStripe: "no" value to "yes"

exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

  return stripe.customers.create({

    email: user.email

  }).then((customer) => {
    return admin.database().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({registeredStripe: "yes"});
  });
});
```

The Stripe customer is created successfully ~ but my realtime database doesn't update at all. I've tried rewriting this line many different ways, but nothing worked.

Edit: I am trying to update my real-time database but no update is being made (trying to change a value from “no” to “yes”.  I get no errors in the log, but no update is made.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen?  Please edit the question to b\e very specific about the outcome you are expecting.  Are there any errors in the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I suggest double checking if there are actually errors in the functions log in the Firebase console.**  I would not expect this code to work at all:

```
return admin.database().collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({registeredStripe: "yes"});
```

`admin.database()` works with Realtime Database, but "collection" and "document" are Firestore methods. This code should generate an error saying that "collection" is not a method.  *Firestore and Realtime Database are completely different databases with different APIs.*

If you want to update Realtime Database, you should use its own API.  You will use methods such as "child" to indicate the location in the database to change.  Please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data).